# Inhibit scrolling of text

Tags: javascript, css, text, position, scroll

I'm making a slide oriented website, similar to a how a parallax site would operate, but so far no js, just css, and obviously no delayed scrolling because there is so far no js.

I am working on the first two slides. On the first slide I have my header and nav at the top, an empty section that was used for an affect with css that uses gradient and transparency and a picture that covers the viewport.

On the second slide, I have a section that represents all of slide2, which contains a different picture that covers the viewport, and some text that's identified by its own div and has a background color and text.

Here's the problem. I was able to get the background-color to stay fixed by using background-attachment and the background-position: top-left of the screen, height: 100%; and width: 15%; This keeps the background from scrolling, but this does nothing for the text.

I need to inhibit the text from scrolling as well, so that its position on the background doesn't change. So instead of the text scrolling onto the background, it's more like a curtain rising and revealing the text underneath.

I've tried position:fixed, but this ruins the transparency affect of the empty section on slide 1, and for some reason ignores any z-index I give it and remains on top of any subsequent slides (oddly, it obeys the z-index of the header, the empty section and the img that make up slide one).

Can I do this with css? I don't know js yet, but I'm learning it, and I know its used often for scrolling affects. So if the only fix is js, I'm not against using it, I just won't understand it atm.

Here is the simplified code:

HTML5

```
<html>
 <head>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="headerContainer">
   <div id="containerRow">
    <header id="home">
     <a href="#home" title="Top"><img id="logo" src="images/logo/MASKAUTONOMY.png" alt="Logo" style="height:75px; margin:25px 0px 0px 25px; padding:0;"></a>
    </header>
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#home" title="Home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#about" title="More Links">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div><!--End containerRow-->
  </div><!--End table headerContainer-->
  <section class="ribbon">
  </section><!--Section left blank to make ribbon with gradient affect-->
  <Section class="slide1">
   <h1>Company Slogan</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="about" class="slide2">
   <div id="slide2Text">
    <h1><span>Mask</span> Autonomy</h1>
    <p class="companyInfo">Some stuff
    </p>
    <p> some more stuff.
    </p>
   </div><!--End of slide2Text-->
  </section>
  <section id="services" class="slide3">
   <ul>
    <li>List of things we do
    </li>
    <li>More things we do
    </li>
   </ul>
  </section><!--End of slide3-->
 </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
  padding:              0px; 
}

#headerContainer {
  height:               10vh;
  width:                100%;
  margin:               0px;
  padding:              0px;
  display:              table;
  position:             relative;
  z-index:              999;
  background-color:         #e1e3e9;
}

header {
  display:              table-cell;
}

nav {
  margin:               0px;
  padding:              0px;
  display:              table-cell;
  width:                100%;
  text-align:               right;
  white-space:              nowrap;
  overflow:             hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-right:             0px;
  padding-right:            25px;
  display:              inline-block;
  *display:             inline;
  *zoom:                1;
  font-size:                1.2vw;
  font-family:              arial;
}

nav ul li:last-of-type {
  margin-right:             47px;
  padding:              0px;
}


.ribbon {
  position:             relative;
  height:               4vh;
  width:                100%;
  background-color:         #e1e3e9;
  z-index:              998;
}

.slide1 {
  color:                #e0e0e0;
  height:               86vh;
  background-image:         url(../../Documents/DOCS/Stycorp/Website/Images/bckgrnd.jpg);
  background-repeat:            no-repeat;
  background-attachment:        fixed;
  background-position:          center center;
  overflow-x:               hidden;
  margin-bottom:            0px;
  padding:              0px;
  position:             relative;
  z-index:              997;
}

.slide1 h1 {
  position:             relative;
  top:                  60%;
  left:                 47px;
  font-size:                4vh;
}

.slide2 {
  position:             relative;
  height:               100vh;
  background:               url(images/Charlotte.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size:          cover;
  z-index:              989;
}

#slide2Text {
  position:             static;
  background-color:         #7d8e9e;
  background-attachment:        fixed;
  background-position:          left top;
  height:               100%;
  width:                15%;
  text-align:           center;
  font-size:            2.33vh;
}

#slide2Text h1 {
  position:             relative;
  top:                  2.5%;
  font-weight:          normal;
  text-transform:       uppercase;
}

#slide2Text span {
  color:                #a9aba5;
  font-weight:          normal;
  text-transform:       uppercase;
}

.companyInfo {
  color:                #e0e0e0;
}

.slide3 {
  position:             relative;
  z-index:              994;
  height:               100vh;
}
```

Ok, maybe not that abbreviated. Sorry. Any ideas how to get the text on slide two to remain on the background-attachement:fixed portion of slide 2 during scrolling without messing up the transparency affect on slide one and allowing slide3 to scroll above slide2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out on my own. Funny, how simple the answer was. All I did was make a second container within the "slide2Text" container that contained the same inline text elements elements, I identified it as "text," and used css to style the background of "slide2Text", and css to fix the text position of "text."

I'm not sure if I like the result as much as I thought I would, but maybe I can use some javascript or css to make the text transition from invisible to visible as the slide scrolls into view.

If anyone wanted to see the code or doesn't understand my answer, just ask and I'll post it. Again, it was a simple fix.